# Mongoose / Express findByIdAndUpdate does not work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I tried methods from Stackoverflow and many other sites, but I could not change the data in my database. I am sending the ID of the product in my database to the specified API. However, nothing is returning. The data is also not updated with the data in the new JSON file I entered. I'm testing it using Postman.

This is my API code from my server.js file.

```js
app.put("/api/product/update", (req, res) => {
  Product.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, doc) {
    res.send(doc);
  });
```

Here is my model file:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   
    name: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
        unique: 1,
        //maxlength
    },

    material: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    },

    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 255,
    },

    productType: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Prodtype',
        default: "Other",
    },

    inStock: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
    }

},{timestamps:true});

const Product = mongoose.model('Product',productSchema);
module.exports = { Product }
```

Postman: `PUT localhost:3000/api/product/update?id=6029812bee921b0c7fb65abf`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you've provided I'm assuming you're using express as your nodejs server framework.

If you want to access your request body, you need to add a [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) as a middleware.

```
$ npm i body-parser
```

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser)

app.put("/api/product/update", (req, res) => {
  Product.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, doc) {
    res.send(doc);
  });
```

In addition I would recommend you to not directly write everything you're receiving on the endpoint to your database but to implement some sort of validation.

Comment: sorry, my problem is not solved. I already use a body-parser in my project. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. When I changed my code as follows, I used req.query instead of req.body.

```
app.put("/api/product/update",(req, res) => {
  Product.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.query.id },
    { name: req.body.name, price: req.body.price, inStock: req.body.inStock },
    function (err, doc) {
      console.log(doc);
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      } else {
        res.send(doc);
      }
    }
  );
});
```